# Why don't I need to dereference a character pointer in C before printing it?

Tags: c

Why does this code work? I would expect that I would need to dereference `ptr`,  `printf("%s\n", *ptr);` before I could print it out, but I get a `Segmentation Fault` if I try to do it that way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char name[] = "Jordan";
        char *ptr = name;
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
}
```

Hope you guys could give me some insight.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you print **string** we need starting address of string.

```
printf("%s\n", ptr);
                ^ address with %s
```

it prints chars till `\0` nul encounter.

Whereas to print **chat** int .. we need **value variable**:

```
printf("%c\n", *ptr);
               ^ * with %c print first char
```

Where as in **`scanf()` a string** you always need to give address:

```
scanf("%s", ptr);
            ^ string address
```

Also for int **`scanf()` a char**

```
scanf("%c", ptr);
            ^ read at first location char address
```

**Note:** `Scanf()` need address with `%c` to store a scanned value in memory.

Be *careful* your `ptr` *points to a constant string so you can't use in scanf*.

> Why **Segmentation fault** with following code ?
>
> ```
>     printf("%s\n", *ptr);
> ```

When you do like this, because of  `%s` printf interprets `*ptr` as an address, but it's actually not an address and if you treat it as address it points to some location that is read protected for your program(process) So it causes a segmentation fault.

Your `ptr` via `name` points to some constant string  in memory ("Jordan") as in below diagram:

```
name 2002
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ 'J' │ 'o' │ 'r' │ 'd' │ 'a' │ 'n' │'\0' │ ........
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
  ^
  |
 ptr = name 

 ==> ptr = 2002
     *ptr = 'J'
```

In `printf("%s\n", *ptr);` the `*ptr = 'J'` and ASCII  value of char 'J' is `74` but `74` address is not under your process control and you are trying to read from that memory location and its a  memory violation and segmentation fault occurs.

If you compile you code containing `printf("%s\n", *ptr);` then with proper option say `-Wall` with `GCC` you will get a warning like below:

`warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`

Says `%s` need (expects ) an address of type `char*` but you are putting value

notice:

```
printf("%s\n",   *ptr);
        ^          ^ argument-2
        argument-1
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because the `%s` format specifier in the format string you pass to `printf` means that the corresponding argument should be a string, not a single character. And in C, a string is a pointer to the beginning of a block of characters that has a null character (byte with a value of 0) at the end.

Basically, this works because you're doing exactly what you're supposed to in order to print a string.

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` formatter to printf expects a "string", which is really a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters.

That is to say, printf *expects* you to pass the pointer to it.  When you dereference the pointer, it's taking the letter J, whose value in ascii is 74 (decimal), and tries treating that as a pointer to an array.  That's an area of memory that's inaccessible, so you get the segmentation violation.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `%s` tells `printf` to expect a pointer to a null-terminated char array. Which is what `name` and `ptr` are.

`*name` and `*ptr` are not. If you dereference them, you'll get back a single `char`, which is basically lying to `printf` - resulting in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`*ptr` is essentially a reference to a single `char`, not to the string of `char`'s. due to this `char *` and `char[]` are essentially the same thing

Answer (score 0):

When you declare char *prt = name thats where you are dereferencing it.  the "*" here isn't part of the variable just a way to show you want what that variable points to.  If you were to put the *prt again in your printf you are doing it twice.  name is an array of characters and *ptr is a dereferenced pointer to those characters.

Hope that explaination helps :-)