# passing array of characters to function in c

Tags: c, pointers

```
void skip(char *msg)
{
  puts(msg+6);
}

char *message="Don't call me";
skip(message);
```

My doubt is why we don't use 
    puts(*(msg+6)) to display text from 7th character onward;
according to me (msg+6) refers to memory and *(msg+6) content

Comment: Yes, but `puts` wants the 'memory' (or rather, a pointer). `*(msg + 6)` is but a single character, not a string.

Comment: then what about printf("%s",msg+6);

Comment: @sandy: `int printf(const char *restrict format, ...);`

Comment: @sandy Same story, `printf` expects a (character-)pointer for every `%s` in the format. I don't understand what you're not understanding...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what you can find in puts manual:

> int puts(const char *s);

as you can see it also expects pointer to a content as a parameter, rather than an actual value.

Answer (score 0):

`*msg` is essentially a reference to a single char, not to the string of char's. due to this `char *` and `char[]` are essentially the same thing and you don't need to dereference character pointer in C because compiler automatically print fully string from given base address upto '\0' not get. you can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841696/why-dont-i-need-to-dereference-a-character-pointer-in-c-before-printing-it) for more info .

Comment: @vikash Can u please elaborate ur statement...char * and char [] are essentially same

Comment: @sandy This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347170/char-array-and-char-array

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void skip(char *msg) {
    puts(msg + 6);
}
int main() {
    char *message = "Don't call me";
    skip(message);
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation.