# Understanding operations with pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have a snippet code in C programing language as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main() {
    char *s="Abhas";
    printf(" s = %s \n", s);
    printf(" s + s[1] = %s \n", s+s[1]);
    printf(" s + s[1] - s[3]= %s \n", s+s[1]-s[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output are:
[image]

So, could you help me to clarify on how we get the second and the last output line. I am a new guy in C.

Comment: What result are _you_ expecting?

Comment: second last printf cause undefined behavior  due to buffer overflow, get an idea from second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15841740/1673391)

Comment: Actually, I need an explaination for the question how the snippet code works, and why I get the output.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I think so. s + s[1] = s + 'a' = s + 62 => error because the string has 5 characters only.

Comment: @PhucNguyen in `s + s[1]`, .. `s[1]` is `'b'` and its ascii value is 98 (assuming ascii implementation ) and `s + s[1]` == `s + 98`  runtime error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf(" s + s[1] = %s \n", s+s[1]);
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf(" s + s[1] = %s \n", s+'b');
```

which is equivalent to:

```
printf(" s + s[1] = %s \n", s+98);
```

That will access memory that it is not supposed to. The program exhibits undefined behavior.

The line:

```
printf(" s + s[1] - s[3]= %s \n", s+s[1]-s[3]);
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf(" s + s[1] - s[3]= %s \n", s+`b'-'a`);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
printf(" s + s[1] - s[3]= %s \n", s+1);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
printf(" s + s[1] - s[3]= %s \n", "bhas");
```

Hence the output.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I will accept your answer after 5 mins. Thanks

Comment: Look like it is the answer that I need. But I don't quite understand only more one thing. The compiler reads from top to bottom, from left right, but in s + s[1] - s[3], why s[1]-s[3] is calculated first?

Comment: @PhucNguyen, I showed the result of `s[1] - s[3]` just for illustration. The real operation will be `s + s[1]` first then the `- s[3]` on the result.

Answer (score 2):

Think of memory laid out like this:

```
   | [0] | [1] | [2] | [3] | [4] | [5] | <- indexes
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
s: |  A  |  b  |  h  |  a  |  s  | nul | <- characters
   |  65 |  98 | 104 |  97 | 115 |   0 | <- integral values (if ASCII)
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

The following expression-address map shows what is happening:

```
s                                -> s       -> &(s[0])
s + s[1]                         -> s + 98  -> &(s[98])
s + s[1] - s[3]  -> s + 98 - 97  -> s + 1   -> &(s[1])
```

Of these, only the first and third are legal as they end up within the bounds of the string. The second is undefined.

The first gives you the address of the string itself, so you see `Abhas`.

The third gives you the address of the second character of the string, so you see `bhas`.

The second gives you something well outside the string and will therefore give you whatever it wants. In fact, as undefined behaviour, it can give you anything, nothing, crash, format your disks, laugh maniacally through your sound card, or even collapse to a naked singularity, taking a large chunk of our planet with it.

---

I should mention of course that, outside of educating you as to how pointers may work, that code should *never* be used or seen in the wild. It is a classic example of how *not* to code.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo for your comment. But I have to mark the answer of @R Sahu, FIFO guy